# IsRandomAccessRequired in .NETCORE.UWP 6.1.5

Tags: c#, uwp

I need IsRandomAccessRequired for downloads. i am using .NETCORE.UWP 6.1.5 and it doesnt have but GitHub Source use 5.0.0 and it have ?

How i to use IsRandomAccessRequired in last .NETCORE.UWP version?

[GitHub Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer/cs/BackgroundTransfer/Scenario5_RandomAccess.xaml.cs)

Comment: For official code sample, you could update `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` to version 6.15. it also works.

Comment: i already used 6.1.5 but it have not

Comment: Your mean the code sample does not work when update to version 6.15 ?